# How to get the correct latitude and longitude coordinates using FindGeoLocation on street addresses

Tags: geography, geodesy

Have a list of street addresses:

```
addresses = {"123 D st, Davis, CA 95616", 
  "140 B St, Davis, CA 95616", "212 E st, Davis, CA 95616", 
  "325 G St, Davis, CA 95616"};
```

I used FindGeoLocation to obtain the coordinates for the street addresses:

```
latlongdavis = FindGeoLocation /@ addresses;
```

Plotted using this code:

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, PointSize -> 0.02, Point /@ latlongdavis}, 
 GeoRange -> {GeoPosition@{38.54, -121.738}, 
   GeoPosition@{38.546, -121.75}}]
```

However, the markers appear in the wrong location. When the street addresses and values in latlongdavis are plotted using Google maps, they are not in the same locations. How do I get the markers to plot in the correct locations the way Google maps does when it is given the street addresses?

Comment: how to find multiple address in google maps at once? Or you have to do it one at a time? Is there special syntax for multiple address location using google maps?

Comment: The points all seem to be within a reasonable margin of error from the Google placements given the nature of street addresses.  Google's specific method is likely proprietary so it seems unsurprising that *Mathematica*'s is a bit different.

Comment: Google locations are not all that accurate. Google Maps thinks my condo is located several hundred feet from where it really is. I would not automatically assume Google's locations are better than _Mathematica_'s.